# split two number using bit operators

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Assuming that I have an variable like:

```
int n = 23;
```

it is possible split it, and convert to:

```
int x = n ?? ??; //2
int y = n ?? ??; //3
```

have no idea how to do this. Any help is very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is going to be ugly, very ugly. It would probably require a variable for an intermediate result, because of the division by five. What's wrong with `int x=n/10; int y=n%10;`???

Comment: Another option is to use BCD (binary coded decimal) numbers. If you're only doing simple operations on the numbers (+/-), it's easy to break the digits out of BCD numbers since each decimal place is represented by exactly 4 bits. just sayin...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not necessary to use bit operators for this. In fact, since bit operators work with the *binary* representation of numbers, they're generally no good for base 10 calculations.

```
int n = 23;
int x = n / 10;
int y = n % 10;
```

Comment: What if int is composed of 3 digits and he vant to split into three? And what if "n" is < of 10 ?

Comment: @Don: Then user834697 is going to have to be more specific about what he wants.

Comment: @DonCallisto: I leave extensions of this method as an exercise for the reader. Once you know how to split off the last digit, the rest is easy.

Comment: @GregHewgill : but he only "suppose" that the variable had that value. I think that a "dynamic" method should be more "corret" as an answer

Comment: there's no an bitwise solution?

Comment: @user834697: No, not in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop to grab each value.  You'll have to keep track of `x` here differently of course, but I think this will work for you.

```
while (n != 0)
{
    x = n % 10;
    n = n / 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

different approach using libc library.  .. there are others as well.

```
 int *
 val2arr(int *arr, const int val)
 {
       char tmp[32]={0x0}; // more than digits in LONG_MAX on 64 bit
       char *p=tmp;
       int *i=arr;
       sprintf(p, "%d", val);
       for(; *p; i++, p++ ) 
           *i=*p - 48;
       *i=-1;          // mark end with -1
       return arr; 
 }
```